# Why Java ReplaceAll with Regex boundaries doesn't work when I add a sharp signal?

Tags: java, android, regex

When I try this code below, it works fine using the regex boundaries:

```
"word john word".replaceAll("\\bjohn\\b","fill")
```

> Result: "word fill word"

But if I need to search for a word that contains "#" it doesn't work:

```
"word john# word".replaceAll("\\john#\\b","fill")
```

> Result: "word john# word"

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

She `#` symbol is not counted as a word character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`), so your word boundary (`\b`) no longer matches.

You could use a positive lookahead and base yourself on the whitespace instead:

```
"word john# word".replaceAll("\\bjohn#(?=\\s+)","fill") // word fill word
```

Or use a non-word boundary (`\B`):

```
"word john# word".replaceAll("\\bjohn#\\B","fill") // word fill word
```

Or nothing at all:

```
"word john# word".replaceAll("\\bjohn#","fill") // word fill word
```

Comment: Thank you , I didn't know about the \\B and in my case I had to add an IF to check if the search string contains # and use \\B or \\b for each condition.